# ¿Como puedo hacer para que una fila se multiplique tantos dias como tenga un mes?

Tags: vue.js

tengo la siguiente tabla, y necesito que la fila donde esta el boton "save" se repita tantos dias como haya en el mes.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

hasta ahora he probado con moment.js, pero no he obtenido resultado.

esa parte de la tabla esta en un archivo aparte. aqui es donde lo 'llamo':

```html
 <v-for>{{moment().daysInMonth()}}</v-for>
 <Dia></Dia>
```

este es el fragmento de 'Dia' donde se encuentra la parte del archivo:

```html
<template>

<tr>
    <th>{{ day.name }}</th>
    <td><input type="time" v-model="EntradaManana"></td>
    <td><input type="time" v-model="SalidaManana"></td>
    <td><input type="time" v-model="EntradaTarde"></td>
    <td><input type="time" v-model="SalidaTarde"></td>
    <td><input type="time" v-model="HorasOrdinarias"></td>
    <td><input type="time" v-model="HorasComplementarias"></td>
    <td><button>save</button></td>
</tr>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Estas usando mal la directiva `v-for`. Puedes usarla de esta forma, asumiendo que `moment().daysInMonth()` es un array:

`<Día v-for="(day, index) in moment().daysInMonth()" ></Dia>`